# How to delete replication controller and its pods in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

What is the command to delete replication controller and its pods?

I am taking a course to learn k8s on pluralsight. I am trying to delete the pods that I have just created using Replication controller. Following is my YAML:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: hello-rc
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    app: hello-world
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-world
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello-ctr
        image: nigelpoulton/pluralsight-docker-ci:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

If I do 'kubectl get pods' following is the how it looks on my mac:

[image]

I have tried the following two commands to delete the pods that are created in the Minikube cluster on my mac, but they are not working:

`kubectl delete pods hello-world`
`kubectl delete pods hello-rc`

Could someone help me understand what I am missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can delete the pods by deleting the replication controller that created them

```
kubectl delete rc hello-rc
```

also, because pods created are just managed by ReplicationController, you can delete only theReplicationController and leave the pods running

```
kubectl delete rc hello-rc --cascade=false
```

this means the pods are no longer managed .you can create a new ReplicationController with the
proper label selector and manage them again

Also,instead of replicationcontrollers, you can use replica sets.
 They behave in a similar way, but they have more expressive
pod selectors. For example, a ReplicationController can’t match pods with 2 labels

Comment: Thank you! I have been able to delete the replication controller using 2nd option that kept the pods running. I was able to subsequently delete the pods as well using `kubectl delete --all pods --namespace=default`

Answer (score 2):

below command is just enough

```
kubectl delete rc hello-rc
```

One more thing is that ReplicationController is deprecated rather ReplicaSets is preferred